# Check if a specific radio button has been selected Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, radio-button

What I'm trying to accomplish is:

When a user clicks the first *Open until Filled* option, leave the *date* input disabled. But when the user clicks on the second *Open Until* radio button. Have the *date* input enabled.

As of right now I can't seem to get it working. It seems to skip my check altogether. Am I missing something?

```
$(function() {
    if ($('input#id_open:checked').length > 0) {
        alert("please fill in the date");
        $('input[name=end_date]').attr('disabled', false);
    }
});
```

I made a [**fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/8KggV/4/) to show what I mean.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: You say "When a user clicks..." however, in your code you don't show any click handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/8KggV/5/

```
$(function() {
    $('input').click(function(){
    if ($('#id_open:checked').length > 0) {
        $('input[name=end_date]').attr('disabled', false);
    }
        else{
            $('input[name=end_date]').attr('disabled', true);        
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

when using jQuery, to detect if a control is checked I use the is method.  As well you don't need to check the length, as the is method return a boolean.

```
$(function() {
    if ($('input#id_open').is(':checked')) {
        alert("please fill in the date");
        $('input[name=end_date]').attr('disabled', false);
    }
});
```

Comment: While this is a valid alternative approach (and slightly cleaner, in my opinion), it does exactly the same thing as what the OP's code does. So it is not really a solution to his/her problem, which is caused by a missing click handler.